# How to uninstall Microsoft Weather and Microsoft Groove in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, system-apps, lumia-640-xl

When I tap on all apps I always find that Microsoft weather app has a blank blue tile and the same thing applies to Microsoft Groove. I have discovered that uninstalling the app and reinstalling it recovers the lost icon as I did with MSN News. Now I can't uninstall Microsoft Groove and Microsoft Weather apps? How do I solve this problem without resetting my device?

For your information these two apps are functioning well except for this somewhat trivial problem.

My phone is a Microsoft Lumia 640 XL running Windows 10 Mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been solved without any intervention from me either with a soft reset or a hard reset. I think Microsoft silently updated their apps. Now Microsoft Weather and Groove tile icons appear correctly in all apps list.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Weather and Groove are OS apps and cannot be removed. Have you tried a soft-reset to fix the problem? (Hold Power + VolumeDown.)

Comment: No, I haven't because I afraid to lose my call history and SMSs.

Comment: @mms911 A soft reset won't lose anything. It's essentially the equivalent of taking the battery out.

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrade to windows 10 mobile on my Lumia 532. Unfortunately soft reset didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Usually these kind of problems you encounter after a W10 upgrade can only be solved by doing a hard reset (which I do recommend).